# SQL Find pairs of rows with next best timestamp match

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, window-functions

My challenge is to find pairs of rows that are adjacent by timestamp and keep only those pairs with minimal distance of a value field (positive values of the difference)

A table `measurement` collects data from different sensors with a timestamp and a value.

```
id | sensor_id | timestamp | value
---+-----------+-----------+------
 1 |         1 | 12:00:00  |     5
 2 |         2 | 12:01:00  |     6
 3 |         1 | 12:02:00  |     4
 4 |         2 | 12:02:00  |     7
 5 |         2 | 12:03:00  |     3
 6 |         1 | 12:05:00  |     3
 7 |         2 | 12:06:00  |     4
 8 |         2 | 12:07:00  |     5
 9 |         1 | 12:08:00  |     6
```

A sensor's value is valid from its timestamp until the timestamp of its next record (same sensor_id).

### Graphical representation

[image]

The lower green line shows the distance of sensor 1's (blue line) and sensor 2's (red line) values over time.

*My aim is*

1. to combine only those records of 2 sensors that match the timestamp logic (to get the green line)
2. to find the dinstance local minimums at

   - 12:01:00 (at 12:00:00 there's no record for sensor 2)
   - 12:05:00
   - 12:08:00

The real table resides in a PostgreSQL database and contains about 5 million records of 15 sensors.

### Test data

```
create table measurement (
    id serial,
    sensor_id integer,
    timestamp timestamp,
    value integer)
;

insert into measurement (sensor_id, timestamp, value)
values
(1, '2020-08-16 12:00:00', 5),
(2, '2020-08-16 12:01:00', 6),
(1, '2020-08-16 12:02:00', 4),
(2, '2020-08-16 12:02:00', 7),
(2, '2020-08-16 12:03:00', 3),
(1, '2020-08-16 12:05:00', 3),
(2, '2020-08-16 12:06:00', 4),
(2, '2020-08-16 12:07:00', 5),
(1, '2020-08-16 12:08:00', 6)
;
```

### My approach

was to pick 2 arbitrary sensors (by certain sensor_ids), make a self join and retain for any  sensor 1's record only that record of the sensor 2 with the previous timestamp (biggest timestamps of sensor 2 with sensor 1's timestamp <= sensor 2's timestamp).

```
select
*
from (
    select
    *,
    row_number() over (partition by m1.timestamp order by m2.timestamp desc) rownum
    from measurement m1
    join measurement m2
        on m1.sensor_id <> m2.sensor_id
        and m1.timestamp >= m2.timestamp
    --arbitrarily sensor_ids 1 and 2
    where m1.sensor_id = 1
    and m2.sensor_id = 2
) foo
where rownum = 1

union --vice versa

select
*
from (
    select
    *,
    row_number() over (partition by m2.timestamp order by m1.timestamp desc) rownum
    from measurement m1
    join measurement m2
        on m1.sensor_id <> m2.sensor_id
        and m1.timestamp <= m2.timestamp
    --arbitrarily sensor_ids 1 and 2
    where m1.sensor_id = 1
    and m2.sensor_id = 2
) foo
where rownum = 1
;
```

But that returns a pair with `12:00:00` where sensor 2 has no data (not a big problem)
and on the real table the statement execution does not end after hours (big problem).

I found certain similar questions but they don't match my problem

- [SQL Join on Nearest less than date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2142907/sql-join-on-nearest-less-than-date/2142950)
- [SQL Join same table based on time stamp and inventory level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33347965/sql-join-same-table-based-on-time-stamp-and-inventory-level)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can run into *stable marriage problem* like complicatitions.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a couple of lateral joins. For example:

```
with
t as (select distinct timestamp as ts from measurement)
select
  t.ts, s1.value as v1, s2.value as v2,
  abs(s1.value - s2.value) as distance
from t,
lateral (
  select value
  from measurement m 
  where m.sensor_id = 1 and m.timestamp <= t.ts
  order by timestamp desc
  limit 1
) s1,
lateral (
  select value
  from measurement m 
  where m.sensor_id = 2 and m.timestamp <= t.ts
  order by timestamp desc
  limit 1
) s2
order by t.ts
```

Result:

```
ts                     v1  v2  distance
---------------------  --  --  --------
2020-08-16 12:01:00.0   5   6         1
2020-08-16 12:02:00.0   4   7         3
2020-08-16 12:03:00.0   4   3         1
2020-08-16 12:05:00.0   3   3         0
2020-08-16 12:06:00.0   3   4         1
2020-08-16 12:07:00.0   3   5         2
2020-08-16 12:08:00.0   6   5         1
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3zVhZ8bxkZXhfGHhgXmAuv/0).

Also, if you want **all timestamps**, even unmatched ones like `12:00:00`, you can do:

```
with
t as (select distinct timestamp as ts from measurement)
select
  t.ts, s1.value as v1, s2.value as v2,
  abs(s1.value - s2.value) as distance
from t
left join lateral (
  select value
  from measurement m 
  where m.sensor_id = 1 and m.timestamp <= t.ts
  order by timestamp desc
  limit 1
) s1 on true
left join lateral (
  select value
  from measurement m 
  where m.sensor_id = 2 and m.timestamp <= t.ts
  order by timestamp desc
  limit 1
) s2 on true
order by t.ts
```

In those cases it's not possible to compute the distance, though.

Result:

```
ts                     v1      v2  distance
---------------------  --  ------  --------
2020-08-16 12:00:00.0   5  <null>    <null>
2020-08-16 12:01:00.0   5       6         1
2020-08-16 12:02:00.0   4       7         3
2020-08-16 12:03:00.0   4       3         1
2020-08-16 12:05:00.0   3       3         0
2020-08-16 12:06:00.0   3       4         1
2020-08-16 12:07:00.0   3       5         2
2020-08-16 12:08:00.0   6       5         1
```

Answer (score 2):

The first step is to calculate the difference at each timestamp.  One method uses a lateral join and conditional aggregation:

```
select t.timestamp,
       max(m.value) filter (where s.sensor_id = 1) as value_1,
       max(m.value) filter (where s.sensor_id = 2) as value_2,
       abs(max(m.value) filter (where s.sensor_id = 2) -
           max(m.value) filter (where s.sensor_id = 1)
          ) as diff
from (values (1), (2)) s(sensor_id) cross join
     (select distinct timestamp
      from measurement
      where sensor_id in (1, 2)
     ) t left join lateral
     (select m.value
      from measurement m 
      where m.sensor_id = s.sensor_id and
            m.timestamp <= t.timestamp
      order by m.timestamp desc
      limit 1 
     ) m
     on 1=1
group by timestamp;
```

Now the question is when does the difference enter a local minimum.  For your sample data, the local minima are all one time unit long.  That means that you can use `lag()` and `lead()` to find them:

```
with t as (
      select  t.timestamp,
              max(m.value) filter (where s.sensor_id = 1) as value_1,
              max(m.value) filter (where s.sensor_id = 2) as value_2,
              abs(max(m.value) filter (where s.sensor_id = 2) -
                  max(m.value) filter (where s.sensor_id = 1)
                 ) as diff
      from (values (1), (2)) s(sensor_id) cross join
           (select distinct timestamp
            from measurement
            where sensor_id in (1, 2)
           ) t left join lateral
           (select m.value
            from measurement m 
            where m.sensor_id = s.sensor_id and
                  m.timestamp <= t.timestamp
            order by m.timestamp desc
            limit 1 
           ) m
           on 1=1
      group by timestamp
     )
select *
from (select t.*,
             lag(diff) over (order by timestamp) as prev_diff,
             lead(diff) over (order by timestamp) as next_diff
      from t
     ) t
where (diff < prev_diff or prev_diff is null) and
      (diff < next_diff or next_diff is null);
```

That might not be a reasonable assumption to make.  So, filter out adjacent duplicate values before applying this logic:

```
select *
from (select t.*,
             lag(diff) over (order by timestamp) as prev_diff,
             lead(diff) over (order by timestamp) as next_diff
      from (select t.*, lag(diff) over (order by timestamp) as test_for_dup
            from t
           ) t
      where test_for_dup is distinct from diff
     ) t
where (diff < prev_diff or prev_diff is null) and
      (diff < next_diff or next_diff is null)
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=cf35f44fae5dff18b14a5bd18b1118c0) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

The infill of missing values requires window functions and a Cartesian product of every minute crossed with your two sensors.

The `invars` cte accepts the parameters.

```
with invars as (
  select '2020-08-16 12:00:00'::timestamp as start_ts,
         '2020-08-16 12:08:00'::timestamp as end_ts,
         array[1, 2] as sensor_ids
),
```

Create the matrix of `minute` x `sensor_id`

```
calendar as (
  select g.minute, s.sensor_id, 
         sensor_ids[1] as sid1,
         sensor_ids[2] as sid2
    from invars i
   cross join generate_series(
           i.start_ts, i.end_ts, interval '1 minute'
         ) as g(minute)
   cross join unnest(i.sensor_ids) as s(sensor_id)
),
```

Find `mgrp` for every time a new value is available from a `sensor_id`

```
gaps as (
  select c.minute, c.sensor_id, m.value,
         sum(case when m.value is null then 0 else 1 end)
            over (partition by c.sensor_id 
                      order by c.minute) as mgrp,
         c.sid1, c.sid2
    from calendar c
         left join measurement m
                on m.timestamp = c.minute 
               and m.sensor_id = c.sensor_id
),
```

Interpolate missing values by carrying forward the most recent value

```
interpolated as (
  select minute, 
         sensor_id,
         coalesce(
           value, first_value(value) over
                    (partition by sensor_id, mgrp
                         order by minute)
         ) as value, sid1, sid2
    from gaps
)
```

Perform the `distance` calculation (`sum()` could have been `max()` or `min()`--it makes no difference.

```
select minute,
       sum(value) filter (where sensor_id = sid1) as value1,
       sum(value) filter (where sensor_id = sid2) as value2, 
       abs(
         sum(value) filter (where sensor_id = sid1) 
         - sum(value) filter (where sensor_id = sid2)
       ) as distance
  from interpolated
 group by minute
 order by minute;
```

Results:

```
| minute                   | value1 | value2 | distance |
| ------------------------ | ------ | ------ | -------- |
| 2020-08-16T12:00:00.000Z | 5      |        |          |
| 2020-08-16T12:01:00.000Z | 5      | 6      | 1        |
| 2020-08-16T12:02:00.000Z | 4      | 7      | 3        |
| 2020-08-16T12:03:00.000Z | 4      | 3      | 1        |
| 2020-08-16T12:04:00.000Z | 4      | 3      | 1        |
| 2020-08-16T12:05:00.000Z | 3      | 3      | 0        |
| 2020-08-16T12:06:00.000Z | 3      | 4      | 1        |
| 2020-08-16T12:07:00.000Z | 3      | 5      | 2        |
| 2020-08-16T12:08:00.000Z | 6      | 5      | 1        |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p65hiAFVT4v3TrjTPbrZnC/0)
```

Please see [this working fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/p65hiAFVT4v3TrjTPbrZnC/0).

Answer (score 1):

Window functions and checking the neigbors.
(you'll need an extra anti-selfjoin to remove the duplicates, and invent a tie-breaker for the *stable marriage problem*)

---

```
SELECT id,sensor_id, ztimestamp,value
        -- , prev_ts, next_ts
        , (ztimestamp - prev_ts) AS prev_span
        , (next_ts - ztimestamp) AS next_span
        , (sensor_id <> prev_sensor) AS prev_valid
        , (sensor_id <> next_sensor) AS next_valid
        , CASE WHEN (sensor_id <> prev_sensor AND sensor_id <> next_sensor) THEN
                CASE WHEN (ztimestamp - prev_ts) < (next_ts - ztimestamp) THEN prev_id ELSE next_id END
        WHEN (sensor_id <> prev_sensor) THEN prev_id
        WHEN (sensor_id <> next_sensor) THEN next_id
        ELSE NULL END AS best_neigbor
 FROM (
        SELECT id,sensor_id, ztimestamp,value
        , lag(id) OVER www AS prev_id
        , lead(id) OVER www AS next_id
        , lag(sensor_id) OVER www AS prev_sensor
        , lead(sensor_id) OVER www AS next_sensor
        , lag(ztimestamp) OVER www AS prev_ts
        , lead(ztimestamp) OVER www AS next_ts
        FROM measurement
        WINDOW www AS (order by ztimestamp)
        ) q
ORDER BY ztimestamp,sensor_id
        ;
```

---

Result:

---

```
DROP SCHEMA
CREATE SCHEMA
SET
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 9
 id | sensor_id |     ztimestamp      | value | prev_span | next_span | prev_valid | next_valid | best_neigbor 
----+-----------+---------------------+-------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------+--------------
  1 |         1 | 2020-08-16 12:00:00 |     5 |           | 00:01:00  |            | t          |            2
  2 |         2 | 2020-08-16 12:01:00 |     6 | 00:01:00  | 00:01:00  | t          | t          |            3
  3 |         1 | 2020-08-16 12:02:00 |     4 | 00:01:00  | 00:00:00  | t          | t          |            4
  4 |         2 | 2020-08-16 12:02:00 |     7 | 00:00:00  | 00:01:00  | t          | f          |            3
  5 |         2 | 2020-08-16 12:03:00 |     3 | 00:01:00  | 00:02:00  | f          | t          |            6
  6 |         1 | 2020-08-16 12:05:00 |     3 | 00:02:00  | 00:01:00  | t          | t          |            7
  7 |         2 | 2020-08-16 12:06:00 |     4 | 00:01:00  | 00:01:00  | t          | f          |            6
  8 |         2 | 2020-08-16 12:07:00 |     5 | 00:01:00  | 00:01:00  | f          | t          |            9
  9 |         1 | 2020-08-16 12:08:00 |     6 | 00:01:00  |           | t          |            |            8
(9 rows)
```